# How can I make a country plot in Sage/Maxima?

Tags: dictionary, modeling, simulation

I heard today that Maxima can do the country plot by contour_plot in Sage.
I tried the following unsuccessfully to import Maxima:

```
from Maxima import contour_plot
```

I would like to make a similar map as [here](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/175564/sage-map.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean a contour plot. Get a quick start and paste this code to your Sage Notobook:

f = lambda x,y: cos(x*y)

contour_plot(f, (-100, 4), (-4, 4))

More examples:

- http://www.flickr.com/photos/sagescreenshots/2131281877/
- http://norsemathology.org/wiki/index.php?title=Benchmarks

Comment: Where can I get the x, y and z -coordinates to draw maps?